# Strange "reduce" method group in JDK8 bulk collection operations library

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8

Why does the new JDK8 [`Stream`](http://lambdadoc.net/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) class contain only the following `reduce` methods:

```
T reduce(BinaryOperator<T> reducer)
T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> reducer)
U reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> reducer, 
    BinaryOperator<U> combiner)
```

but not an obvious method which corresponds to `reduce`/`fold` functions found in other languages (e.g. Haskell `foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a`) and which could look like this:

```
U reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> reducer)
```

?

Instead there is a similar method which has an extra `combiner` argument. I'm not even sure how to use it since the API documentation I linked to above does not use this argument in the example, it only mentions its required properties.

Why are the JDK8 methods made like this, and how can I emulate standard `fold` behavior with them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `reduce`-like data-parallel operations serve as general value-aggregation operations over a data set (e.g. an array of elements). You can use them to implement, for example, the sum.

The order in which the values of the data set are combined together (e.g. summed) is not specified, so they do not correspond to `foldl` found in Haskell or `reduceLeft`/`foldLeft` found in Scala.

The extra `combiner` argument in the third line is used when the result type of the aggregation is different than the type of your elements. In these cases you have to specify how to combine two results together.
Lets say you want to implement a count of vowels in a string using the third reduce. The data elements are characters and the `reducer` specifies how a character and the current count are combined:

```
(Integer count, Character c) -> if (isVowel(c)) count + 1 else count
```

The combiner will just be a sum:

```
(Integer count1, Integer count2) -> count1 + count2
```

[Scala Parallel Collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html), for example, has these [for a while now](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq) (search for `aggregate`).

Comment: Very helpful answer, thanks, but I had to think for a few minutes to see the connection between the presence of the combiner and the order-independence (and hence parallel-friendliness) of the third version.  To spell it out for people as slow as I am: without a way of combining two `U`s, the reducer only has the `BiFunction<U, ? super T, U>` to work with, which means that it can only process one `T` at a time, effectively serializing the operation.

Comment: Exactly - I might have been a bit hand-wavy, very nicely explained.

Comment: Thank you both very much, it became much clearer now. However, I still do not understand how can I emulate standard fold behavior. In other words, I guess it is possible that I have well-defined reducer, but no well-defined combiner (or writing it is hard/inconvenient), and I do not mind having `reduce` working sequentially. What should I do then?

Comment: In case you don't care about parallelism and want serial execution, it should be easy to code a Scala-style `foldLeft` in Java 8, using an iterator over the collection and a function object.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the reason that the API doesn't provide this is that the designers don't want encourage people to write non-parallelizable code. Any time you find that something "obvious" is missing from the API, that's likely to be the reason (apart, of course, from the cases where they just ran out of time).

Comment: @axel22, well, I thought that this could be done directly with streams operations, but it seems that it is not possible. Thanks for explanations.